# changing commit message after push from android studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github, version-control

Please can any one help me how to change commit message after push from inside the android studio.I am using android studio in the windows OS.I know there is git push -f origin command but as I already told you I am pushing and making changes from android studio itself.It would be great if anyone can help me with this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Once you push the changes its considered final.

So if you have already pushed you can do this.
`git reset --soft HEAD~1` (Pushes back head 1 back with you changes in the current head as uncommited change)
Now do a commit(appropriate message, no push) from android studio.
Now do a

```
git push -f origin branch
```

from the folder.